# Execute multiple commands at the same time

Tags: command, sh

Hey so I was wondering how can I make it so that in my sh script two commands execute at the same time without waiting for one another to finish. As an example I'd like zmap to run and a listener.pl

How could I do this? I know doing this will run zmap then after zmap is over it will run the 2nd command
but I need both to be executed at the same time.

```
#/bin/sh
zmap 
perl listener.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the jobs in the background by appending `&` to each command.

```
#/bin/sh
zmap &
perl listener.pl &
wait
```